# How to disable swipe back gesture globally in ionic 4 angular project

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, gesture, ionic4

Already tried to achieve this with:

```
<ion-router-outlet swipeGesture="false" animated="false"></ion-router-outlet>
```

and in app.module:

```
IonicModule.forRoot({
    swipeBackEnabled: false
}),
```

config.xml:

```
<preference name="AllowBackForwardNavigationGestures" value="false" />
```

..but horizontal swipe gestures still trigger navigation to other pages :-(

Possible ways i can think of and tried partially but unsuccessfully are:

1. use deprecated ionic navController somehow?
2. use hammerJS?
3. use undocumented GestureController
   (https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/tree/a77ee2a6f88e8defb1763b71e77410264fafac70/core/src/utils/gesture)

If someone can point in the right direction or provide an example how to disable swiping, mainly for iOS, i would be very glad, thx a lot

Comment: I would like to do the same. Have you found an answer?

Comment: @AndreasGassmann unfortunately not - i am working around it - watching routes and redirect accordingly, but not satisfying at all.

Comment: @AndreasGassmann thank you, i was just missing the brackets around swipeGesture. gosh :-D

Comment: Happens to all of us :). Glad I could help you.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I solved it by adding `[swipeGesture]="false"` to the `ion-router-outlet` as described here: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/16441

At first, I made the mistake of adding it to all `ion-router-outlet`s in my `tabs.html` file. That didn't work. Instead, you only have to add it to the `ion-router-outlet` in the `app.component.html` file. That did the trick for me.

app.component.html

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-router-outlet [swipeGesture]="false"></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-app>
```

I'm using ionic version `4.0.0-beta.17`.

Comment: This is nice and all, but has the global config been working for anyone yet?

Comment: This doesn't work on child pages having back button.

Comment: Surprisingly contrary to the other comments, this is working for me on my only existing `ion-router-outlet` inside `app.component.html` for `"@ionic/angular": "^4.7.1"`

Answer (score -1):

```
<ion-menu [swipeGesture]="false"> </ion-menu>
```

in Ionic4 version (To remove SwipeGesture in all pages)